# XML validation using XSD assertion condition

Tags: xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have below XML and XSD and I am getting some error while validation.

**My XML**

```
<parent>
  <child1>Y</child1>
  <child2>Y</child2>
</parent>
```

**My XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="child2" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assertion test="child1 != 'N' and child2 != 'N'" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`
```

**The error I'm getting**

> s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_parent' is invalid. Element 'assertion' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

I want to pass the XML validation If I get other than 'N' value for child elements.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: does the tool you're using support XSD 1.1 ?

Comment: I was validating online using below url:

https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: I have tried by using java 7 as well.
It has propagated  the same issue.